# MS Bot Framework Nodejs unable to connect bot after deployment on azure

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework

I have deployed my nodejs bot to azure with proper appId and password configuration. The URL to the site works but when I test my bot connection (see below), I get this message....

"NotFound. The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

When I try to reach my /api/messages end point on localhost, I get the same error.

I have followed core concept and bot framework examples very closely to build my bot. Back-end server is not my strength so any help would be appreciated.

[error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olYeE.png)

**Updated with code:**

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var restify = require('restify');
var request = require('request');

//Server setup
var server = restify.createServer();

server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function() {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});

//Get secrets from server environment
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});

//Create chat bot
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
//Handle bot framework messages
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());
server.get(/.*/, restify.serveStatic({
    'directory': '.',
    'default': 'index.html'
}));

//LUIS Model
var model = process.env.model || 'https://api.projectoxford.ai/luis/v1/application?xxxxxxx';
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(model);
var dialog = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer]});
```

[bot connection error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSlJo.png)

Comment: If its not working on local host , maybe your route is set up incorrectly.  Can you share the part of your code that sets up the listener/port and maybe an emulator screenshot?

Comment: @JimLewallen i updated with my codes. thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the route that directs to `index.html`.

You can fix this by assigning the route handler to a specific path, such as `'/'` or `'/docs'` etc.

Working route handler example code:

```
server.get('/', restify.serveStatic({
    'directory': '.',
    'default': 'index.html'
}));
```